# how to send json data to splunk HEC or splunk enterprise

Tags: java, groovy, splunk

I need to send JSON data from Jenkins pipeline to Splunk. I am able to make JSON data. I am referring 
[How do I send JSON files to Splunk Enterprise from JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555219/how-do-i-send-json-files-to-splunk-enterprise-from-java) this link.
I am getting an error when line no. 5 : httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(eventStr); has been called . 
please help...

```
 DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://<SERVER>:8088/services/collector/event");
 httppost.addHeader("Authorization", " Splunk <token id>");
 String eventStr = "{sourcetype=_json, index=main, event={ <JSON> }}"
 httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(eventStr);
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 System.out.println("response: " + entity);
```

Comment: you just missed a closing bracket @ line 5

Comment: normally, an error message explains you the problem. just read them ;)

Comment: I did it sir.. will try once again

Comment: May I make you request? if you can share code snippet with classes you import in code https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna wager your error message says something like "`unexpected token at <character count> on <line number>`"

You are missing some close parenthesis (before the semicolon) on line 5, and seem to need some semicolons on lines 2 & 4